# Using .horizontal ScrollArea at top of screen?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I'm trying to render a layout with a title area, horizontal scroll view, then more views below that. I've wrapped everything in a ZStack to allow me to expand one of the child views in the horizontal area to expand and fill the top 1/3 of the screen (like the App Store) when they're clicked.

```
    ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello World").foregroundColor(.pink)
            
            ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                HStack(spacing: 20) {
                    ForEach(0..<2) {
                        Text("H/Item \($0)")
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .frame(width: 200, height: 180)
                            .background(Color.red)
                    }
                }
            }.background(Color.orange)
            
            Spacer()
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background(Color.green)
        .foregroundColor(.white)
    }
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    .foregroundColor(.white)
    .background(Color.pink)
    //.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
```

If I comment out the `edgesIgnoringSafeArea` XCode complains that updating the preview took more than 5 seconds (running in the simulator only gives me a white screen). I guess it's a bug in SwiftUI, but is there a way to render the children of a ScrollView outside of its visible bounds?
I can re-position the views using GeometryReader, but they're clipped if the coordinates are outside of the ScrollView.

[image: ScrollArea(.horizontal)]

Comment: Why do you try to move it a top? Title, ie *Hello World* now, will not be visible, so what's the goal?

Comment: @Asperi I need to have some header text there. The issue is that to show the red view at the top (ignoring the safe area) the ScrollView needs to needs to have offset(y: -n) so that it is at the top edge of the screen. As soon as I make that change, the view no longer renders at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible solution (irrelative to goal, because anyway I could not understood why needed Text at the top, `cause finally it is anyway invisible). Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4.

[image: demo]

```
var body: some View {
    ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello World").foregroundColor(.pink)

            ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                HStack(spacing: 20) {
                    ForEach(0..<2) {
                        Text("H/Item \($0)")
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
                            .frame(width: 200)
                            .background(Color.red)
                    }
                }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
            }
            .frame(height: 180)
            .background(Color.orange)
        }
        .background(Color.green)
        .foregroundColor(.white)
    }
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .top)
    .foregroundColor(.white)
    .background(Color.pink)
    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
}
```